# Cannot get nopCommerce to work on godaddy hosting version 4.2

Tags: asp.net-core, nopcommerce

HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway

There was a connection error while trying to route the request.

Most likely causes:
•The CGI application did not return a valid set of HTTP errors.
•A server acting as a proxy or gateway was unable to process the request due to an error in a parent gateway.

**Things you can try:**

•Use DebugDiag to troubleshoot the CGI application.
•Determine if a proxy or gateway is responsible for this error.

**Detailed Error Information:**

Module
   AspNetCoreModule

Notification
   ExecuteRequestHandler

Handler
   aspNetCore

Error Code
   0x8007000d

Requested URL
   http://localhost:15536/

Physical Path
   C:\Users\HenryP\Desktop\NopCommerce_4.2.0\src\Presentation\Nop.Web

Logon Method
   Anonymous

Login User
   Anonymous

More Information:
This error occurs when a CGI application does not return a valid set of HTTP headers, or when a proxy or gateway was unable to send the request to a parent gateway. You may need to get a network trace or contact the proxy server administrator if it is not a CGI problem. 
View more information »

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not CGI issue. Newest nopCommerce version run on .net core version and require Full Trust. And my experience used Godaddy in the past that they didn't support Full Trust, so you can't install nopCommerce on their platform. You better contact their support team or you can ask this issue on nopCommerce forum. But, it seeems that nopCommerce can't run well on Godaddy platform. If you use nopCommerce, I recommend you can check Asphostportal.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, this is a generic error for when IIS can't find the specified .NET Core components ,and doesn't know where to forward requests.So i suggest you to check once you select asp.net or asp.net core while creating your site